# My Api is returning the Error "No matching route for request." together with all my requested data

Tags: php, json, rest, api, codeigniter

I am hitting an API to get results but all my GET request return the same error. It also returns the data which I need. My API is written in Codeigniter.
**Here is the error:**

```
{
"Error": [
{
"Message": "No matching route for request."
}
]
}{"error":"false","data":[{"id":"7","title":"Interior"},{"id":"8","title":"Exterior"},

{"id":"9","title":"Under
Coat"},{"id":"10","title":"Wood\/Metal"}]}
```

**Here is the code of same file:**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/validation.php");
class Categories extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->model('category_model');
        $this->load->database(); 
        $this->load->helper(array('url')); 
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->library('session');   
        $this->load->library('curl');
        $this->Validation = new Validation(); //--------------- Called the Validation Class
    }

    ///// Remaping functions to check if the function user is calling exists or not
    function _remap($method)
    {
        $method = $method.'_'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if(method_exists($this,$method))
        {
            call_user_func(array($this, $method));
            return false;
        }else{
            echo '{ "Error": [ { "Message": "No matching route for request." } ] }';
            exit;
        }
    }

    // ##################################################################################
    //                                                                                  #
    //              Add / Update Category                               #
    //                                                                                  #
    // ##################################################################################
    public function index_post()
    {
        $result = $_POST;

        //------------- Name validation
        if($this->Validation->is_empty_string($result['title']) == true){
            $message = array('Error' => array("Type" => "Error","Code" => "400","Message" => "Category title is missing."));
            $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
            //http_response_code(403);
            echo $jsonMsg;
            exit;
                }else{
                    $title = $result['title'];
                }

                /*
                 * If id than update else add
                 */

                if(isset($result['id']) && $result['id'] != ''){
                    $id = $result['id'];
                    $results = $this->category_model->update($id, $title);
                }else{
                    $results = $this->category_model->add($title);
                }

        if (!empty($results)){
            //------------ Sending perameers to Mobile and Web
            $message = array('error' => 'false','data'=>$results);
            $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
            //http_response_code(202);
            echo $jsonMsg;
        }else{
            $message = array('error' => 'true','data' => 'No record found');
            $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
            //http_response_code(403);
            echo $jsonMsg;
        }
    }

    // ##################################################################################
    //                                                                                  #
    //          Get Categories                                      #
    //                                                                                  #
    // ##################################################################################
    public function index_get()
    {

            if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != ''){
                $result = $this->category_model->get($_GET['id']);
                $products = $this->category_model->getProductsAgainstCategories($_GET['id']);
                $result = array_merge($result[0],$products);
            }else{
                $result = $this->category_model->get();
            }


            if (!empty($result)){
                    //------------ Sending perameers to Mobile and Web
                    $message = array('error' => 'false', 'data' => $result);
                    $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
                    //http_response_code(202);
                    echo $jsonMsg;
            }else{
                    $message = array('error' => 'true', "data" => "No record found");
                    $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
                    //http_response_code(403);
                    echo $jsonMsg;
            }
    }

        // ##################################################################################
    //                                                                                  #
    //          Delete Category                                     #
    //                                                                                  #
    // ##################################################################################
    public function index_delete()
    {

            if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != ''){
                $result = $this->category_model->delete($_GET['id']);

                //------------ Sending perameers to Mobile and Web
                $message = array('error' => 'false', 'data' => 'Successfully deleted');
                $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
                //http_response_code(202);
                echo $jsonMsg;
            }else{
                $message = array('error' => 'true', "data" => "Nothing to delete");
                $jsonMsg = json_encode($message);
                //http_response_code(403);
                echo $jsonMsg;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: What URL you're hitting for the API?

Comment: http://mobipaints.com/colorapp/apis/categories

Comment: I see this is due to _remap function, REST_Controller already check for the route not exists. you can just remove that function and everything will work fine :)

Comment: @prashant I tried this but the same error

Comment: I have a same project on different server but that works fine, i don't know what's wrong

Comment: can you plz try replace: 

    require APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

with 

    require_once(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

Comment: @prashant Still same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203983/discussion-between-hasnain-ghias-and-prashant).